# start up issue when cold

Tags: starting, rpm, cold

need an advise please.
When im starting the car from a cold engine, i need like 5 turns with the key before it holds the rpms.
To be precise. It always starts up, but the rpms go down to around 300 for about 2-3 seconds and then car chokes and dies. 
after it gets to hold the rpms, drives ok, starts up ok. but the first “after a 4-5 hours of standing start up” struggles and asks for the multiple times.
im selling the car in a month but really need it in the meantime and afraid ill have to change the fuel pump or smthng which is a lot of money to put in it.

its a vw bora 2l petrol. 1999
putting shell petrol in it only.
ignition leads with spark plugs changed 8 months ago.
eats oil.. or at least it used to before i’ve put some fancy additive which has managed to stop that but havent checked the spark plugs since.
slight misfire when driving on a motorway but nothing major i think.

any advice?

Comment: was thinking if it cant be getting some “fake air” somewhere. but i would assume that holding gas pedal down would help. but it doesnt

Comment: You don't want to "hold the gas pedal down". Try nudging the gas very gently after it starts but before it dies.

Comment: tried as well, didnt work. just struggles a bit longer and dies

Comment: Sounds like a fuel pump to me. Can you get access to an OBD scanner and software to check the fuel pressure?

Comment: It's possible the fuel rail pressure is dropping while it sits. Try turning the ignition switch "on" until the fuel pump cycles off (about 5-7 seconds). Do this 2 or 3 times. Then see if it will start like it does when  warm.

Comment: ok thank you will try that. another thing noticed. its about 15 degrees and the coolant thermostat shows 90 straight away. might not have anything to do with it. just sayin. as it wasnt happening before and the coolant lvl is ok

Comment: all the same. nothing has changed :/ but its pretty weird that the engine reached the operating temp after 2-3 minutes but never go above it.